# Evaluate $\int_c z^2\ dz$, where the curve $c$ is the line $x^2+y^2=\tan^{-1}(x,y)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, line-integrals

given the line $c$: $\Re(z)^2+\Im(z)^2=\arg(z),$

[image: x^2+y^2=\tan^{-1}(x,y)]where $y$ is the imaginary part and $x$ is the real
$$$$i want to evaluate $$\int_C z^2\ dz, z=x+iy$$
so:
$$
\int_C z^2\ dz=\int_C\left(x+iy\right)^2\left(dx+idy\right){=\int_C\left[\left(x^2-y^2\right)dx-2xy\ dy\right]+i\int_C\left[2xy\ dx+\left(x^2-y^2\right)dy\right]}
$$im stack here, how can i continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\int_{\gamma}z^2dz=\left[\frac{z^3}{3}\right]_{P}^Q$$
where $P$ is the starting point and $Q$ is the final point of the path $\gamma$.

P.S. BTW, what is the definition of $\arg(z)$? Is it the principal value with range $[0,2\pi)$?

Comment: this question was given to be before i learned about cauchy theorem so i would like to know if there is a way to do this without using it

Comment: No need of Cauchy Theorem here. Just use the definition of contour integration! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#For_continuous_functions

Comment: so because that my start and end point are on the real axis than $y$ and $dy$ are equal to $0$ and i get $\left[\frac{z^3}{3}\right]_{P}^Q$?

Comment: No, $P$ and $Q$ can be anywhere. More simply, the COMPLEX derivative of $z^3/3$ is $z^2$.